# To meet WCAG, should I change the corporate colour?

Tags: accessibility, wcag2.0

I have a question regarding to the text colour usage to meet WCAG 2.0, our website colour is using #00B140 (Green) with white background (#FFFFFF). It is our corporate logo green colour which we would like to use cross-through the website. However, based on the contrast checker, #00B140 on #FFFFFF only has the ration rate of 2.85 (WCAG 2.0 needs to meet 4.5).
We are in Ontario and our AODA will effect in June 30. My question will be: should we mandatorily need to change the green or we can stay with the green?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that logos are not held to WCAG color contrast standards.

> "*Text that is part of a logo or brand name has no contrast requirement*"
> https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum.html

As for the rest of your site, you will need to modify the color somewhat to meet [SC 1.4.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum) if you are using it in combination with white backgrounds or text.

That doesn't *necessarily* mean that you need to modify your corporate colors, which can be a particularly hard sell to the client/boss. You can definitely keep using the #00B140 color, as long as it isn't used as a background/foreground to text. You can certainly use the light green as part of the visual design of your website/app template.

If there are areas where you do need the green to be a background/foreground to text, then you will need to darken it. If it's only being used for large text ( ≥18.5px bolded, or ≥24px not bolded ), then you can go with a less drastic 3:1 contrast ratio, which would be a pretty minor change from where you are at now.

I've worked on several sites where the corporate colors had to be modified. If you're changing the color of text (like headings for example), then it's pretty hard to tell unless it's a really drastic change.

If you're creating design elements that need an offset background color (i.e. not white), then maybe consider going with a color that contrasts or compliments your existing corporate color(s) and is still able to meet the contrast requirement.

Comment: +1 - minor thing @Josh its 18.5px **if it is bold** (14pt) - 24px (18pt) **if not bold** for large text rules to apply (and I blame WCAG being a rambling mess making it so damned confusing!), other than that  a fantastic answer!

Comment: Excellent point. Thank you, sir. I will update my answer.

Comment: Sir? I am certainly not a sir  hehe.